# Can I ask questions related to my assignments here?

Tags: discussion, networking

I have been asked to design a network topology as per the given requirements in my assignment. I've already created the network topology using visio, but I am not sure if its correct. So I need someone to have a look at it.

Comment: This is a bad question. Your Title is wrong it doesn't relate to what your actual question is. Then you continue to present your real question but you're leaving out all the important information. What are the requirements? What does your topology design actually look like? Either add a [picture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) or use an online service like [draw.io](http://www.draw.io). Of course we're not there to solve your homework but you could try to post it regardless. At least if you put work into it.

Comment: IMHO, you can ask questions as long as they're somewhat _useful_. Asking to explain how things work is useful, to certain extent. Dropping a bunch of assignments and asking us to work them out isn't useful.

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1133961/network-of-an-organisation) seems oddly familiar.

Comment: I not hopping to get it done for me. I just want to know if its correct @grawity

Comment: @JeseRodeiz What you want isn't helpful to anyone else.  Don't cheat!  Cheating is defined by, often by professors, as using any unapproved resources.

Answer (score 9):

Not in the manner you're asking.

Lets say you have an assignment involving visio, and you can't quite beat the thing into submission, sure. Ask a specific question of the sort you see here.

If you want someone to vet your homework, or to do your homework, no.

Answer (score 5):

No. This site is to help people having problems and seeking answers about their PC. If you need help on your homework then you should look for a site more catered to your needs.

On the other hand, if they are questions based on programs (for instance powerpoint) then I'm sure you can ask them here.

Comment: Except if the question involves us creating a PowerPoint or providing verification, the PowerPoint the author created, is "correct".  Homework questions, within scope of this website, are not questions that are within the script of this website.  In other words, we will NOT, do your homework.